# SELECT MATERIALIZE

Tags: html-select, materialize

select is not behaving well.

it is necessary to double-click to show the options.

is it possible to solve?

http://archives.materializecss.com/0.100.2/forms.html

Answer (score 1):

I Found a solution

```
setTimeout(function () {
                    var kelle = $('.select-wrapper');// $('.select-wrapper');
                    $.each(kelle, function (i, t) {
                        t.addEventListener('click', e => e.stopPropagation())
                    });
                }, 500)
```